# BotFramework: 'State size exceeded configured limit.'

Tags: c#, azure, emulation, bots, botframework

I'm devloping a bot and whenever I PostAsync herocards (50 hero cards) in a formflow, in the end it gives me an error message: 'State size exceeded configured limit.' from Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DLL

Error happens when try to setPrivateConversationData 
Below the error on Emulator:

```
  "key": {
    "channelId": "emulator",
    "conversationId": "i99caeb8n2h7",
    "userId": "default-user"
  },
  "state": {
    "eTag": "1506952139325",
    "data": {
      "ResumptionContext": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "isTrustedServiceUrl": true
      },
      "DialogState": "H4sIAAAAAAAEAOx9B2AjWX........",
      "ServiceUrl": "http://localhost:1460"
    }
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "MessageSizeTooBig",
    "message": "State size exceeded configured limit."
  }
}
```

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/troubleshoot-general-problems#is-there-a-limit-on-the-amount-of-data-i-can-store-using-the-state-api), there is a limit on the amount of data you can store using the default State capabilities. Each state store (i.e., user, conversation, and private bot data bag) may contain up to 64kb of data.

You will have to store less info or to provide your own storage mechanism.

The following article shows how to manage state data using CosmosDb: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-cosmosdb

Comment: So when an image is sent in a conversation it can't exceed the limit of 32kb? I didn't have any problems before, what happened?

Comment: Yes it can be larger, the image is not being stored in the state.

Comment: This is my post, and obviously the reason for this exception is slightly different then.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645806/webclient-downloaddata-throws-an-exception-in-bot-framework?noredirect=1#comment80240816_46645806

Comment: I just replied to it.