# WebClient.DownloadData throws an exception in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, .net, exception, webclient, botframework

I am uploading an image and using WebClient with DownloadData to get the byte array, but now it throws me an exception:

```
Exception: State size exceeded configured limit.
[File of type 'text/plain']
```

I haven't noticed such behaviour before with the exact same image. What might have gone wrong?

```
private async Task SendPhoto_ActivityReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        Activity activity = await result as Activity;
        Activity activityReply = activity.CreateReply();

        if (0 < activity.Attachments?.Count)
        {
            if (activity.Attachments.FirstOrDefault().ContentType.Equals("image/jpg") ||
                activity.Attachments.FirstOrDefault().ContentType.Equals("image/jpeg") ||
                activity.Attachments.FirstOrDefault().ContentType.Equals("image/png") ||
                activity.Attachments.FirstOrDefault().ContentType.Equals("image/tiff"))
            {
                picImage = activity.Attachments.FirstOrDefault().Name;

                HttpClient httpClient= new HttpClient();
                picImageFile = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(activity.Attachments.FirstOrDefault().ContentUrl);

                await context.PostAsync("Want to send another?");

                context.Wait(SendAnotherImage_ActivityReceivedAsync);
            }
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:** Changed the WebClient to HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync and the problem remains.
The exception is shown in the Bot Emulator right after the PostAsync is executed

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527098/botframework-state-size-exceeded-configured-limit

Comment: You need to attach full stack trace. I doubt that's DownloadData throws this exception. It should be some Bot Framework code, like PostAsync.

Comment: btw you can replace `0 < activity.Attachments?.Count` with `activity.Attachments?.Any()`. and why using webclient instead of httpclient?

Comment: Yes, its after PostAsync that happens actually. The DownloadData itself doesn't throw an exception, but noticed that when I remove that line everything is fine. (Yet I don't have other way to get the byte[] so it's not actually fine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `picImageFile` is a variable inside of your dialog, and so it's being saved in the state because the dialog is serialized. Two options

1. Download the image and process it in that method, without saving it in memory
2. Save the byte array in an external storage.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!