# AuthBot with Azure Table Store

Tags: c#, .net, azure-storage, botframework

I'm using authbot ([AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot)) to login users on my bot, but, I'm using a large amount of data, and since than, it starts gives me an error that I'm overload ([Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527098/botframework-state-size-exceeded-configured-limit))

So, I do as suggested, I create an [Azure Table Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-state-azure-table-storage), since than, my bot does not recognize the authentication. It seems Authbot cannot get \ set the data from table storage. Do you know something about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current AuthBot uses the default state client.  I've submitted a PR to fix this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot/pull/37/files

In the interim, you can download the AuthBot source and include the changes to OAuthCallbackController in your project.

Edit:
This repo will eventually replace AuthBot: https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth  It is already using the correct state client interfaces.